# IPhone JSON Array to Variables

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have an array left over after parsing JSON that looks like ( -122.1407313, 37.7012704, 0 ) , How do I put them seperately into variables without an object or index to call?
I tried:

```
NSArray *coordinates = [point objectForKey:@"coordinates"]; //holds the array above
NSString *lat = [coordinates objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *lon = [coordinates objectAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: What JSON parser are you using? If you got numbers in your JSON you might as well have `NSNumber` objects instead of `NSString`s. What are the error messages?

Comment: Its SBJson, yeah, I should be using NSNumber, would this have an effect on it? No error messages.

Comment: I lied, its giving an uncaught exception: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSDecimalNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x47eeb50'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like:

```
NSNumber *lat = (NSNumber*)[coordinates objectAtIndex:0];
float latValue = [lat floatValue];
```

Comment: I am actually getting an error on build saying error: pointer value used where a floating point value was expected